# How can I debug a service which won't shutdown error 2189

Tags: .net, vb.net, service

I have created a number of Windows services using VB.NET. They startup and run swimmingly. They wake up periodically and check a table in an Oracle database, do some stuff and go back to sleep. Occasionally the service hangs with no logging which is one problem that I need to debug.

But the first problem I want to troubleshoot is;

```
net stop "XXService"
The service could not be controlled in its present state.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2189.
```

This will happen even when everything is running smoothly, and the services are waking up and processing the data properly.

Currently when the service wakes up, I write to a log file. Is there something I can write to the log file to help debug this?

BTW To stop the service I kill the process.

Edit:

Based on the comment below, I did use ambiguous terminology. To clarify To sleep I use;

```
Friend WithEvents MainTimer As System.Timers.Timer

'Required by the Component Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

' NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Component Designer
' It can be modified using the Component Designer.  
' Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.MainTimer = New System.Timers.Timer
    CType(Me.MainTimer, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    '
    'MainTimer
    '
    Me.MainTimer.Enabled = False
    Me.MainTimer.Interval = intMainTimerInterval
    '
    'ALService
    '
    Me.ServiceName = "ALService"
    CType(Me.MainTimer, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()

End Sub
```

Elsewhere I do;

```
Private Sub MainTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles MainTimer.Elapsed
    Dim intCurrentHour As Integer = Date.Now.Hour
    MainTimer.Enabled = False
    If bolInitializationComplete = False _
    Then
        Logger(intDebug, "Waiting for initialization to complete.")
    Else
        If intCurrentHour < intStopHour And intCurrentHour >= intStartHour _
        Then
            Logger(intDebug, "Before checkAbslink")
            checkAbslink()
            intMainTimerInterval = intMainTimerInterval * 2
            If intMainTimerInterval > (intMaxSecondsToSleep * 1000) _
            Then
                intMainTimerInterval = (intMaxSecondsToSleep * 1000)
                intFileLogLevel = intTempFileLogLevel
            End If
            MainTimer.Interval = intMainTimerInterval
            Logger(intDebug, "After checkAbslink, sleeping " & CStr(intMainTimerInterval / 1000) & " seconds.")
        Else
            Logger(intInfo, "Waiting for Processing Hours")
            Logger(intInfo, "Current Hour=" & CStr(intCurrentHour) & " Start Hour=" & CStr(intStartHour) & " Stop Hour=" & CStr(intStopHour))
            intMainTimerInterval = (600 * 1000) ' 10 minutes
            MainTimer.Interval = intMainTimerInterval
        End If
    End If
    MainTimer.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Edit:

As requested in the comment here are the onStart and onStop subs;

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    strPath = Trim(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
    intIndex = strPath.LastIndexOf("\") + 1
    strPath = strPath.Substring(0, intIndex)
    strRootPath = strPath
    getInitilizationParameters()
    Logger(intInfo, "Finished loading Initialization parameters")
    bolInitializationComplete = True
    MainTimer.Interval = 1000

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    bolStopping = True
    Logger(intInfo, "OnStop initialized")
    While bolProcessing
        RequestAdditionalTime(2000)
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
    End While
    bolProcessing = False
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
End Sub
```

I can see a potential problem in onStop, but I would expect a "hang" when stopping situation. Not an Error 2189.

Comment: How do you make your service "go back to sleep" ? One of the downsides of using vague terms is that it's hard for us to glean technical details that might be relevant..

Comment: Edited question with explanation.

Comment: Have you overridden OnStart and OnStop?

Comment: As they say in Minnesota, "You betcha."

Comment: What's the code in those? Is there any code anywhere that could block the thread running it? What is the last line of the log immediately before you try a stop and get it to hang?

Comment: @PaulStearns Instead of just logging, have you tried `Debug.Assert(False)` and then debug in Visual Studio?

Comment: Added onStart & OnStop to question at the end.

Comment: @JayV I plead ignorance regarding what you are referring to. Also the environment in which the service runs does not have VS on it.

Comment: You can attach the service to the visual studio and debug it same as any windows form application.